# How can I make a program wherein the user can choose what kind of database to open or to connect to?

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

I created a program wherein the selected database will open in the jtable and it will print the report and can save it as .pdf .docx and so on. The sql statement I used is a fixed one or hard coded meaning when I run the program it will automatically connects to the database I wrote in the system. It needs to be changeable where in the user can choose what database to open and will create a report review.

This is the default connection statement right? wherein the connection is fixed and cannot be change?

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
      "jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbaprod1:1544:SHR1_PRD", username, passwd);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Thing, 
 If you really want user to choose which database to open then you have to read the database name , username , password and even You have to get the ip address of the computer containing the database.

```
     //The url will change according to the user's input
     String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@amrood:1521:EMP";
     String USER = "username";
     String PASS = "password"
     Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
```

Second Thing,
  Even after you get the ip address of the computer containing the database you can only access the databse if the user has permited remote sharing or control to the file.

ThankYou. I hope this was helpful

Comment: thank you so much for the help :) I also created a jfilechooser so the user can choose which database to use. Is it possible to link the jfilechooser in the connection statement?

Comment: If the file name is same as the database name you are trying to acess then yes, else you cant. Welcome.

Comment: lo u can see a right mark beside my answer just click on it! :D